# Count number of records where the same value appears in one of three fields

Tags: sql, odbc, relational-database

Table structure for this question:

```
TABLE Roster; FIELDS {IDNum},{FavChs},{2ndFavChs},{3rdFavChs}
```

I'm trying to determine how many records that have the same value in one of three fields. If I'm just looking in one column, it's simple:

```
Select FavChs, Count(IDNum)
FROM Roster
WHERE FavChs is not null
Group by FavChs
```

However, I need to check if the same value is found in any one of three fields for other records. It doesn't matter which field it's in, just that it's in one of them. So if the table was:

```
| IDNum | FavChs | 2ndFavChs | 3rdFavChs |
|-------|--------|-----------|-----------|
|   1   | Swiss  |   Brie    |   Feta    |
|   2   | Swiss  |   Feta    |   Cheddar |
|   3   | Cheddar|   Swiss   |   Cheddar |
|   4   | Feta   |   Swiss   |   (null)  |
|   5   | Feta   |   (null)  |   (null)  |
|   6   | Brie   |   Cheddar |   (null)  |
|   7   | Swiss  |    Swiss  |   Swiss   |
|   8   | Swiss  |   Brie    |   Cheddar |
```

I'd need the results to show:

```
| Cheese | Count |
|--------|-------|
|  Brie  |   3   |
| Cheddar|   4   |
|  Feta  |   4   |
|  Swiss |   6   |
```

Comment: If your table is not too huge - use `UNION` with 3 separate SELECTs and then aggregate.

Comment: Tag your qestion with the database you are using.

Comment: The expected result of Swiss should be 6 given the data provided

Comment: @GordonLinoff Got that updated, thanks. ODBC
ev350 Good eye! Updated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select c.Cheese, count(r.IDNum) as Count
from
(
  select distinct FavChs as Cheese from Roster
  union
  select distinct 2ndFavChs as Cheese from Roster
  union
  select distinct 3rdFavChs as Cheese from Roster
) c
join Roster r
on (r.FavChs = c.Cheese or r.2ndFavChs = c.Cheese or r.3rdFavChs = c.Cheese)
group by c.Cheese
```

Remember to use Union instead of Union All, to make sure all of the values in query C are distinct

Comment: This errors out after about 45 minutes, I might have mentioned that there are a little over half a million records and the table has about 30 other fields.

I did add try adding to the end:

```
Having 
 Count(ARENID)>10
```
To try and speed it up but to no avail. Do you know anything that might speed the query up?

Comment: How long does it take to just get a distinct set from one column? `select distinct flvchs from rooster`. Which dB are you using? Have you tried doing an explain? Have you tried adding an index to each column?

Comment: @AidanKane A distinct set from just one is about 5 seconds. I'm using a relational ODBC

Comment: @JHarper the DB engine itself makes a big difference. While 0.5M rows isn't a big deal for one engine, it could be a showstopper for another.

Comment: @AidanKane Oh! sorry, we're using intersystems cache